# Optimize list selected

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint-2013, filtering

I have gallery into my project, when page loads it charge all upload images and categories like these:

[image]

As you can see, It suit images depending of selected categories. The problem is the page going to slow because it loads all images... How can I do to optimize these process? I think some like delete All categorie, but I don´t know how to do my query to start for example with office categorie filter

There is my code:

```
function GalleryCatPopulate(url, listname, target) {

var eng = false;
if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
    eng = true;
}


 // Getting our list items
 $.ajax({
    url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?   $select=Title,English",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        completeGalleryCat(data, target, eng);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        failureGalleryCat(data, target);
    }
});
}

function completeGalleryCat(data, target, eng) {
var items = data.d.results;
var prefix = "";
var sufix = "<div class='clear'></div>";
if (eng)
   prefix = "<div class='filter selected' data-category='cat-all'>All</div>";
else
    prefix = "<div class='filter selected' data-category='cat-all'>Todas</div>";
var menu = "";
var cat = "";
var title = "Transporte de Materiales";
console.log(title.replace(/\s/g, "_").replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''));
for (var item in items) {
    if (eng)
        cat = items[item].English; 
    else
        cat = items[item].Title;

                menu += "<div class='filter' data-category='" + cat.replace(/\s/g, "_").replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') +"'>"+ cat +"</div>";

        }
$(target).html(prefix + menu + sufix);

}

function failureGalleryCat(data, target) {
$(target).text("There is something bad wit load images, please check console");
}

function GalleryContentPopulate(url, listname, target) {

var eng = false;
var queryGallery = "$select=Title,Description,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/Title&$expand=Categoria/Title";

if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
    queryGallery = "$select=TitleEnglish,DescriptionEnglish,Enlace,EncodedAbsUrl,Categoria/English&$expand=Categoria/English";
    eng = true;
}


// Getting our list items
$.ajax({
    url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$top=1000&" + queryGallery,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        completeGalleryContent(data, target, eng);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        failureGalleryContent(data, target);
    }
});
}

function completeGalleryContent(data, target, eng) {
var items = data.d.results;
console.log(items);
var menu = "";
var cat = "";
for (var item in items) {
if(items[item].DescriptionEnglish==null)
    items[item].DescriptionEnglish="";
if(items[item].Description==null)
    items[item].Description="";
    if(items[item].Categoria.results!= null &&    items[item].Categoria.results!= undefined && items[item].Categoria.results.length > 0){
        cat =setCategories(eng,items[item].Categoria.results);
    }
    if (eng){

        menu += "<div class='mega-entry " + cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "</div><p>" + items[item].DescriptionEnglish + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><div class='mega-link mega-red'></div><a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div>   </div>";
      }else{
        menu += "<div class='mega-entry "+ cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><p>" + items[item].Description + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><div class='mega-link mega-red'></div><a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='"+ items[item].Title +"'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div></div>";
    }
}
$(target).html(menu);
  var api = $(target).megafoliopro(
                {
                    filterChangeAnimation: "pagebottom",            // fade, rotate, scale, rotatescale, pagetop, pagebottom,pagemiddle
                    filterChangeSpeed: 400,                 // Speed of Transition
                    filterChangeRotate: 99,                 // If you ue scalerotate or rotate you can set the rotation (99 = random !!)
                    filterChangeScale: 0.6,                 // Scale Animation Endparameter
                    delay: 20,
                    defaultWidth: 980,
                    paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    paddingVertical: 10,
                    layoutarray: [9, 11, 5, 3, 7, 12, 4, 6, 13]     //    Defines the Layout Types which can be used in the Gallery. 2-9 or "random". You can define more than one, like {5,2,6,4} where the first items will be orderd in layout 5, the next comming items in layout 2, the next comming items in layout 6 etc... You can use also simple {9} then all item ordered in Layout 9 type.
                });

        //console.log("entra");
        // FANCY BOX ( LIVE BOX) WITH MEDIA SUPPORT
        jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
        //console.log("sale");

        // THE FILTER FUNCTION
        $('.filter').click(function () {
            $('.filter').each(function () {    jQuery(this).removeClass("selected") });
            api.megafilter(jQuery(this).data('category'));
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
var categorySelected = getParameterByName("Category");
$("div[data-category='"+categorySelected +"']").click();

}

function failureGalleryContent(data, target) {
console.log(data);
$(target).text("Error loading parallax. Please check console for more info");
 }


function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function setCategories(boolLang, objResult){
var cat ="";
for(var item in objResult){
 if(boolLang)
    cat += replaceAll(" ", "_",objResult[item].English.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')) + ' ';
 else
    cat += replaceAll(" ", "_",objResult[item].Title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')) + ' ';
}
return cat;
}

function replaceAll( find, replace,string) {
return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
 }
  function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
 }
```

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: When the user click a categorie, just load the images for this categorie not all.  And when the user click to see all image ( all categories), load X image on the page, like the maximum amount for the height of the user webpage. And when the user scroll the webpage it loads the second part and again and again ... ( keep the id of the displayed image and fetch you data with a where clause )

Comment: Yes, I want to do that but I don´t have idea how, can you help me ?@Furtiro

Comment: I cannot provide you some code i don't know your project, but with my comment you can do what you want to achieve :/

Comment: If you still have this problem, i can try to help you if you want

Comment: I change my code, so now, if I delete All categorie and when page loads it load ""Office" categorie, the problem is plugin still loads all images in background instead of load each one if categorie is selected @Furtiro

Comment: this is plugin I use [Megafolio](http://hastypudding.org/assets/lib/megafolio/documentation/documentation.html)

Comment: Can you show or edit the code in your api ? Where you get all your images ? That's here that you have to make a where and not send all the images but only the wanted categorie's images

Comment: Use a plugin is a good idea, it seems pretty good, but you'll have to edit your data sending to match what you want

Comment: I´m getting all images via Ajax in this line  `url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$top=1000&" + queryGallery,`

Comment: I didn't ask the url or how you make the request, it doesn't matter. I meant to edit your REQUEST CODE, like in your function getbytitle, to query only the selected categorie and not return a "SELECT * " or get all . When the user click you request only the selected categorie

Comment: Yes I can edit my code

Comment: Can you post the code of "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle()" method ? It's there that you have to get only the image from your selected categorie